# Accessing Windows shares of a passwordless user using Samba

Tags: windows, samba, shared-folders

I have a laptop running Windows 7. Only one account is configured on it, and it does not have a a password.

I try to access its shares from a PC running Ubuntu 14.04, configured to be in the same workgroup, and attached to the same local network.

Both Nautilus and smbclient are unable to access it. For example

```
$ smbclient //<server>/<share> -U <user>
Enter <user>'s password: 
Anonymous login successful
Domain=[WORKGROUP] OS=[Windows 7 Ultimate 7601 Service Pack 1] Server=[Windows 7 Ultimate 6.1]
tree connect failed: NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED
```

(I just press Enter when asked for a password).

The irony is that, when the account on the Windows laptop is configured to have a password, and the correct password is entered, the connection works.

In theory, it should work in both cases: if there's no password, and no password is entered, there should be no reason to deny access. So, why doesn't it work? Does Samba consider "empty password" as a special case?

Answer (score 2):

You need to modify your Windows configuration in order to do this. From [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18442846/792066):

> Go to Control Panel > Network and sharing center > Change advanced sharing settings > Enable Turn Off password protect sharing option

Once you changed this option everything should work.

Note that this effectively strips any protection you can have against attackers from modifying your shared files. I would recommend to actually set up a password and add to the fstab an automount entry with the password saved.

Answer (score 1):

After much torture and redundant torment I have a partial solution. I did the following:

```
apt-get install samba-client
apt-get install cifs-utils
```

Then I issued the following command:

```
sudo mount.cifs //192.168.0.2/f$ /mnt/f -o user=administrator
```

It prompted me for a password, and I just pressed enter instead of putting one, and just as quickly as I pressed enter the share was mounted.

It's not a total solution,  but at least now I can access the shares.

Unfortunately support is still broken in nautilus etc. as they use some other mechanism to access the shares.

You won't be able to just type `smb://192.168.0.2/f$` or whatever to access you shares, because you will get stuck in the login loop, because the file manager still can't handle passwordless shares.

But at least this way you can mount the passwordless share to a folder and access said folder via the file manager.

You will have to do this every time you want to access a passwordless share unless you edit some configurations or something.  It will still be inconvenient if you're at a friends house trying to access shares, but it's better than nothing at this point.

Anyway just modify the command to fit your needs like changing the IP/share,
location where you want it mounted, and the username of the account with the shares.

```
sudo mount.cifs //192.168.0.2/f$ /mnt/f -o user=administrator
```

This is the only way I've seen and know of to properly access a passwordless administrative share, and I'm sure it will work with regular passwordless shares.

If anyone figures out how to make the file browsers work with `smb://` I'd still like to know, I can't figure it out it and doesn't look like anyone else knows either.

Comment: worked perfectly for me. thank you very much!